# Using a trigger to set an application-defined "last modified date" for Case

Tags: trigger

Need a field on the cases that is the true last modifed date. So if we send an email, modify the case, or adds any activity or comment, this date field updates to NOW().
I need help with writing a trigger. I am new to development and they need it our org. When a case record is modified the date should reflect it. 
This is how far I could get:

```
   trigger truedate on Case(before insert, before update) {
   Set<Id> whatIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Case c : trigger.new) whatIds.add(c.WhatId); 

   Map<Id, Case> CseMap = new Map<Id, Case>([select id, true_date1__c from Case where id in :whatIds]);
     Case C;
for(Case c : trigger.new) {
    if (! CseMap.contains(c.WhatId)) continue; 
    C = CseMap.get(a.WhatId);
    C.true_date1__c = c.true_date1__c;
    CseMap.put(t.WhatId, C);
}
try {
    update CseMap.values();
} catch(Exception e) {
   Trigger.new[0].addError(e.getDmlMessage(0));
}
 }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.  People here are unlikely to write you a trigger from scratch, but are often willing to help work out problems.

Comment: Need a field on the cases that is the true last modifed date. So if we send an email, modify the case, or adds any activity or comment, this date field updates to NOW()

Answer (score 2):

LastModifiedDate is automatically set whenever a record is inserted or updated.

Typically you need not to care about that, even for your custom objects.

But my guess is that you are looking for somthing different: are you looking to update LastmodifiedDate every time when a comment is added to the case?

If so, it can be done with a workflow as described here:   https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gumeAAA

You need no trigger.